# How to write a math parser in TeX?

Tags: macros, calculations

TeX is not really good in calculating, so some packages and LuaTeX were developed. But none of these solutions offers symbolic/exact mathematics, so I have tried something like this:

```
% Plain TeX
\catcode`\@=11

% add 2 rational numbers, expandable macro
\def\@rational@add#1#2#3#4{%
    \ifnum\numexpr#2*#4 < \z@
      \expandafter\the\expandafter
        \numexpr\expanded{%
            (-#1*#4-#2*#3)/\expandafter\@gcd\expanded{%
                {\the\numexpr#1*#4+#2*#3\relax}{\the\numexpr#2*#4\relax}}}\relax
      /
      \expandafter\the\expandafter
        \numexpr\expanded{%
            (-#2*#4)/\expandafter\@gcd\expanded{%
                {\the\numexpr#1*#4+#2*#3\relax}{\the\numexpr#2*#4\relax}}}\relax
    \else
      \expandafter\the\expandafter
        \numexpr\expanded{%
            (#1*#4+#2*#3)/\expandafter\@gcd\expanded{%
                {\the\numexpr#1*#4+#2*#3\relax}{\the\numexpr#2*#4\relax}}}\relax
      /
      \expandafter\the\expandafter
        \numexpr\expanded{%
            (#2*#4)/\expandafter\@gcd\expanded{%
                {\the\numexpr#1*#4+#2*#3\relax}{\the\numexpr#2*#4\relax}}}\relax
    \fi}

% helper macros:
\def\@sgn@of@int#1{%
    \ifnum #1 = \z@
      0%
    \else
      \ifnum #1 > \z@ 1 \else -1 \fi
    \fi}
\def\@abs@of@int#1{\ifnum #1 < \z@ \the\numexpr-#1\relax \else \the\numexpr#1 \fi}
\def\@gcd#1#2{%
    \ifnum #2 = \z@
      \@abs@of@int{#1}%
    \else
      \expandafter\@gcd\expanded{{#2}{\the\numexpr #1-#2*(#1/#2)\relax}}
    \fi}

% example
$$ \@rational@add{89}{-24}{-55}{36} $$ prints -377/72 as expected

\bye
```

But writing `\@rational@add` and similar macros all the time ... :(
Some packages are able to parse somthing like `3/4 + 1/3 * ...` and transform it into the right macros.
But I don't understand how they do it. Can someone help me?

My dream would be writing somthing like `\mathexpr 8^(1/2) + 32^(1/2)` which typesets `6 \sqrt2`. I don't know if this is possible in TeX or LuaTeX.

Comment: Possibly interesting documents https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~fateman/papers/parsing_tex.pdf http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/calculator/calculator.pdf

Comment: Have you looked at sagetex? it's an interface to using Sage Math which does symbolic math.

Comment: Also there is some mechanism available to call Python, in which one could use `sympy`.

Comment: But I have not seen any solution for Plain TeX (for Sage and Python). :(

Comment: What do you mean “Plain TeX” solution? In your code you are already using eTeX extension of “expressions”, so why not just use the `xint` bundle (which can run under plain TeX, with eTeX extensions of course)?

Comment: I mean Plain Lua-/Xe-/PDFTeX. As far as I know `\xint` uses  floating point arithmetics.

Comment: I see. But then TeX must have knowledge about `e`, `pi`, etc., since `\mathexpr limit( (1+(1/2)/n)^n, n to infty )` should print out `\sqrt{e}` and so on… I cannot even image the scale of such project…

Comment: @user125730 `sympy` can be used directly in LaTeX (not plain TeX) by using `pythontex`

Comment: @Ruixi Zhang: But do you have an idea how to start such a project? (Maybe the scale would be smaller for LuaTeX, but I don't know enough about Lua.)

Comment: @user125730 why do you even want to do this in TeX? It's way easier to setup a small script that calculates things with a real computer algebra system and outputs stuff in a mark-upped way and then run TeX on the results. I don't really see the point in programming this in TeX (and that comes from someone who programs in TeX as a hobby).

Comment: @Skillmon likes topanswers.xyz: Not an easy question. It would be something completely new, I would learn so much in TeX programming. This is one of my hobbies, too. If you have an idea, please let me know. :)

Comment: @user125730 iirc, there is a LaTeX package that supports calculations on the rational numbers, but I can't remember the name.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments above indicate, the `sagetex` package is worth looking into.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex,amsmath}
\begin{document}
Is your dream to write:
$8^{1/2} + 32^{1/2}= \sage{8^(1/2)+32^(1/2)}$
or $\sage{8^(1/2)}+\sage{32^(1/2)}=\sage{8^(1/2)+32^(1/2)}$?
\end{document}
```

Gives the output:
[image]

No difficult coding required. The `sagetex` package uses the computer algebra system [SAGE](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/index.html) which is not part of your LaTeX installation. That means either SAGE should be installed on your machine or you access it using a free [Cocalc account](https://cocalc.com). Since installation of SAGE can be tricky for some computers, I'd recommend opening a Cocalc account. Search this site for numerous posts showing what can be done.

Comment: How is CoCalc relevant here?

Comment: I've edited my explanation to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look on this package. Maybe it is possible to adapt it to Plain TeX.

Comment: From [here](https://cocalc.com/doc/latex-editor.html), "You can choose between PDF Latex, XeLaTeX or LuaTeX." and the link for [LuaTex](http://www.luatex.org/) says, "LuaTeX is an extended version of pdfTeX using Lua as an embedded scripting language".