# How to divide in LaTeX without it rounding or truncating?

Tags: calculations, e-tex, dimension-expressions, floating-point

I'm working on a diagram and I'm pretty new to LaTeX, so I've decided to try to do it using math instead of statically assigned values. I have come up with the following:

```
\newcommand\qoffset{14}
\newcommand\smallx{8}
\newcommand\smally{4}
\newcommand\py{\the\numexpr\smally * (\qoffset / (\qoffset - \smallx))}
\the\numexpr\qoffset / (\qoffset - \smallx)
```

The answer should be 9.3 for `\py` but the division is rounding (or truncating) and I need decimal point precision. How would I go about doing this?

NOTE: I am not dead set on using `\the\numexpr`, it's just what I found when trying to figure out how to do math.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\numexpr` works only on integers.  If you want decimals you have to use `\dimexpr` (note that you have to add the `pt` unit to the numerator):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\dimeval#1{\strip@pt\dimexpr#1\relax}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\newcommand\qoffset{14}
\newcommand\smallx{8}
\newcommand\smally{4}
\dimeval{\qoffset pt / (\qoffset - \smallx)}

\dimeval{\smally pt * (\qoffset / (\qoffset - \smallx))}
\end{document}
```

which results:

> [image]

which is correct for the first one, but not as much for the second (it should be `9.33333`).

The second one is wrong (depending on your point of view) because `\dimexpr` only does integer division and multiplication, so (replacing the values) `4pt * ( 14 / ( 14 - 8 ) )` evaluates to `4pt * ( 14 / 6 )` then to `4pt * 2.33333`, and `2.33333` truncates to `2` and the result is `8`.  You can get a bit closer with

```latex
\dimeval{\smally pt * \dimeval{\qoffset pt / (\qoffset - \smallx)}}
```

but a bit wrong is still wrong.

---

If you want *real* floating point arithmetics (without having to worry about units), use `\fpeval` from the `xfp` package:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\qoffset{14}
\newcommand\smallx{8}
\newcommand\smally{4}
\fpeval{\qoffset / (\qoffset - \smallx)}

\fpeval{\smally * (\qoffset / (\qoffset - \smallx))}
\end{document}
```

which results

> [image]

---

As Mico says, you might want rounding.  If want for typesetting numbers the best option is the `siunitx` package:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\num[round-mode=places, round-precision=5]%
  {\fpeval{4 * (14 / (14 - 8))}}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

but if you want to round for further calculations, then you can use the `round` function directly (the syntax is `round(<num>,<digits>)`):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}
\begin{document}
\fpeval{round(  4 * (14 / (14 - 8))  ,5)}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: +1. :-) One could add that if the OP wishes to display the number rounded to, say, 3 digits, he/she could do so by (a) loading the `siunitx` package and (b) typing `\num[round-mode=places, round-precision=3]{\fpeval{\qoffset / (\qoffset - \smallx)}}`, i.e., by encasing the result of the calculation in a `\num` directive.

Comment: `\dimexpr` is really weird.  It will not do what you expect for `a / b` but it will do for `c * a / b`.  So I usually make a scratch `\dimen`, write 1pt to it and use the second form to get proper floating point division.

Answer (score 4):

Would you consider using LuaTeX? Then you could evaluate even more complicated expressions:

```
% gobble ".0" for integers and rounding function
\begingroup
\catcode`\%=12
\directlua{
   function math.round_int ( x )
     return x>=0 and math.floor(x+0.5) or math.ceil(x-0.5)
   end
   function math.round ( x , n )
     return math.round_int ( x*10^n ) / 10^n 
   end
   function gobblezero(x)
     local y = math.round ( x , 8 )
     if y == math.floor(y) then
       return string.format ( "%.0f", y )
     else
       return math.round(y, 7)
     end
   end}
\endgroup

\def\fpeval#1{\directlua{tex.print(gobblezero(#1))}}

$$ \root 6 \of {64} = \fpeval{64^(1/6)} $$

With rounding:
%
$$ 1/3 = \fpeval{math.round(1/3, 1)}... $$

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Nice example! Though I have to say that `xfp` is a mostly IEEE-754 compliant floating point engine, so `\fpeval{64^(1/6)}` and `\fpeval{round(1/3, 1)}` produce the same output as Lua (and it's engine-independent :-)

Comment: You are right of course, but if someone uses LuaTeX he can avoid many lines of code by using the floating point engine from Lua. ;) This should also be faster, I think.

Comment: Indeed, using a built-in floating point engine is a lot faster than the macro emulation.

Comment: Writing such macros is extremly difficult. I wanted to try this as I like programming in TeX, but I gave up soon. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540758/how-to-write-a-math-parser-in-tex

Comment: The implementation is indeed extremely complex.  The `xfp` package I mentioned uses the expandable floating point engine from `expl3`.  Take a look at the [`l3fp` implementation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/l3kernel/source3.pdf) (section 24, around page 700) if you're interested (I tried to understand the implementation, but have failed so far :-)

Comment: No chance for me as well... Too much macros, too much underscores... :D